# How to fix this problem of invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]

Tags: esp8266, wifi, nodemcu, web-server, iot

Im working with node mcu ESP 8266 and trying to make it a webserver but keep encountering this problem.

````
   #include<ESP8266WiFi.h>
    WiFiClient client;
    WiFiServer server(80);
    void setup() 
    {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    WiFi.begin("network","password");
    while(WiFi.status()!= WL_CONNECTED)
    {
      delay(200);
      Serial.print("...");
    }
    Serial.println("NodeMCu is connected");
    server.begin();
    }
    void loop() 
    {
    client = server.available();
    if(client==1)
    {
       String request= client.readStringUntil("\n");
      Serial.println(request);
    }
    }
    ```

I'm getting this error :error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]
   24 |    String request= client.readStringUntil("\n");
      |                                           ^~~~
      |                                           |
      |                                           const char*
````

Comment: Please copy the exact error message, including the line where the compiler finds the error. Also put your code in a code block (" {}  " when editing).

Comment: BTW, the problem is in the `client.readStringUntil("\n")`. The double quotes make the `\n` into a c-string (`const char *`), but it expects a single character (`char`). You can correct this by changing `"\n"` into (single quoted) `'\n'`, which makes it into a single character.

Comment: I assume this is "off-topic" because the bug is not specifically about the Arduino. Given OP's level of experience, they had no way to know that.  I expect many other Arduino novices will encounter this same error and come here looking for an explanation.  Is this really so off-topic?